# How can I get the android header again?

Tags: android-studio

[Hello professionals. I'm new to android studio. I lost the studio header .how can I get this header again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0GOE.png)

Comment: So what is exactly your problem? Your tab bar disappeared?

Comment: Yes. My tab bar disappeared. Please, give me the solution.

Comment: Done, mark it as correct if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is press `CTRL+SHIFT+N`, then it will open a menu, find where you see **All**, and then type **Appearance**. And then select Main menu, and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Then upvote the answer and mark it as correct

Comment: I need at least 15 reputations to cast a vote. But I don't have.